# How do I plot the output of Solve as a function?

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have a system of equations (13 eq) and I want to solve for `S`. There are four solutions in terms of `k` and `Ca`. I don't know how can I convert the solution `S` into a function of `k` and `Ca` so as to be able to plot it.

```
    lambda = 0.1;
    Ma = 0.1;
    R = 2;
    Q = 1;
        eqs = {A1 + B1 - C2 == 0,
       -A1 + B1 - C3 == 0,
       I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma) + G1 + G0 - G2 + I*PP2/Ma == 0,
       I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma) - G1 + G0 - G3 - I*PP3/Ma == 0,
       Ma*(-k*(I*G2 + PP2/(k*Ma)) + PP2/Ma*(1 - k)) + PP1 - PP2 + 
         k^2*xi1/Ca == 0,
       Ma*(k*(-I*G3 - PP3/(k*Ma)) + PP3/Ma *(1 - k)) - PP1 + PP3 - 
         k^2*xi2/Ca == 0,
       Q*R*(I*k)*(A1 + B1) - 
         I*k*C2 - (lambda*Ma/2)*(2*I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma) + G1) + 
         Ma/2*(-k*G2 - I*PP2/Ma*(1 - k) + 
            I*k*(I*G2 + PP2/(k*Ma) + PP2/Ma)) + I*k*xi1*(1 - Q*R^2) == 0,
       Q*R*(I*k)*(-A1 + B1) - 
         I*k*C3 - (lambda*Ma/2)*(-2*I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma) + G1) + 
         Ma/2*(k*G3 - I*PP3/Ma*(1 - k) + 
            I*k*(-I*G3 - PP3/(k*Ma) - PP3/Ma)) + I*k*xi2*(1 - Q*R^2) == 0,
            S*(-Q*A1 - k*C2) + (-A1/R - k*C2) + (1 - Q*R)*I*
          k*(I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma) + G1 + G0) == 0,
            S*(-Q*A1 + k*C3) + (-A1/R + k*C3) + (Q*R - 1)*I*
          k*(I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma) - G1 + G0) == 0,
            -S*xi1 + (I*G2 + PP2/(k*Ma)) + PP2/Ma == 0,
           S*(xi1 - xi2) - I*k*(I*k*PP1/(lambda*Ma)*(2/3) + 2*G0) == 0,
       xi1 - xi2 == 0};

    soln = Solve[
       eqs, {S, A1, B1, C2, C3, PP1, PP2, PP3, G0, G1, G2, G3, xi1, xi2}];

 soln1 = soln[[2]];
 sigma= soln1[[1]];
```

Comment: Help > Documentation Center > Solve > Scope > Basic Uses notes "Use ReplaceAll (/.) to replace x by solutions:..."

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
S2[Ca_, k_] := Evaluate[S /. soln[[2]] // Simplify];
```

this gives the expression `S[Ca,k]` for the second part of `soln`